# Is my golang func run time analysis correct?

Tags: algorithm, go

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGulL.png)

This code snippet is for give two slice of binary number a1 and a2 to return sum slice r1, and I want to figure out how long spend with this code snippet figure out the result.

and I figure out the factorial result.

Is my analysis right?
my analysis for time complexity is:
`cn + (n*n!) + c`

the Code is:

```golang
func BinaryPlus(a1 []int, a2 []int) []int {
    var r1 = make([]int, len(a1), 2*(len(a1)))
    for i := 0; i < len(a1); i++ {
        r1[i] = a1[i] + a2[i]
    }
    // 二分反转
    ReverseSlice(r1)
    r1 = append(r1, 0)
    final := 0
    for i := 0; final != 1; i++ {
        isOver := 1
        for j := 0; j < len(r1); j++ {
            if r1[j] > 1 {
                r1[j] = r1[j] % 2
                r1[j+1] += 1
                if r1[j+1] > 1 {
                    isOver = 0
                }
            }
        }
        if isOver == 1 {
            final = 1
        }
    }
    // 二分反转
    ReverseSlice(r1)
    return r1
}

func ReverseSlice(s interface{}) {
    n := reflect.ValueOf(s).Len()
    swap := reflect.Swapper(s)
    for i, j := 0, n-1; i < j; i, j = i+1, j-1 {
        swap(i, j)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code as text instead of images. SO is well-equipped to render snippets of code. And if you have to use an image for some reason, then try to embed it into the post rather than just pasting a link.

Comment: The code has been added, Tks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear that your code, as written, is correct. The size cap for your result array could be too small. Consider the case that `len(a2) > 2*len(a1)`: the `r1 := make(...)` will not reserve enough in this case. Further, the initial `for` loop will miss adding in the more significant bits of `a2`.

Binary addition should have no more than *O(n)* complexity. You can do it with a single `for` loop. `n = 1+max(len(a1),len(a2))`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func BinaryPlus(a1 []int, a2 []int) []int {
    reserve := len(a1) + 1
    if x := len(a2) + 1; x > reserve {
        reserve = x
    }
    hold := 0
    maxBit := 1
    ans := make([]int, reserve)
    for i := 1; i <= reserve; i++ {
        hold = hold / 2
        if i <= len(a1) {
            hold += a1[len(a1)-i]
        }
        if i <= len(a2) {
            hold += a2[len(a2)-i]
        }
        ans[reserve-i] = hold & 1
        if hold != 0 && i > maxBit {
            maxBit = i
        }
    }
    return ans[reserve-maxBit:]
}

func main() {
    tests := []struct {
        a, b, want []int
    }{
        {
            a:    []int{1},
            b:    []int{0},
            want: []int{1},
        },
        {
            a:    []int{1, 0},
            b:    []int{0, 0, 1},
            want: []int{1, 1},
        },
        {
            a:    []int{1, 0, 0, 1},
            b:    []int{1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
            want: []int{1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
        },
        {
            a:    []int{0, 0},
            b:    []int{0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
            want: []int{0},
        },
    }
    bad := false
    for i := 0; i < len(tests); i++ {
        t := tests[i]
        c := BinaryPlus(t.a, t.b)
        if !reflect.DeepEqual(c, t.want) {
            fmt.Println(t.a, "+", t.b, "=", c, "; wanted:", t.want)
            bad = true
        }
    }
    if bad {
        fmt.Println("FAILED")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("PASSED")
    }
}
```